# How do I get the itemWriter to create the files?

Tags: java, gradle, spring-batch

My ItemWriter is not writing any files. After debug it stops at ItemProcessor. My project should receive information from the Mongo DB then read it, process it, then create .txt files and store the information in said file. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

BatchConfig:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableBatchProcessing
   public class BatchConfig {
private static final Logger LOG =LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfig.class);

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private PaymentPortalJobListener listener;
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Bean
public MongoItemReader<PaymentAudit> mongoReader() throws 
UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    LOG.info("Inside Mongo Item Reader Method");
    MongoItemReader<PaymentAudit> reader = new MongoItemReader<PaymentAudit> 
 ();
    reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    reader.setCollection("paymentAudit");
    reader.setTargetType((Class<? extends PaymentAudit>) 
    PaymentAudit.class);
    reader.setFields("{rxFname, rxLname}");
    reader.setQuery("{rxFname, rxLname}");
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction> 
    (1);
    sorts.put("rxFName", Sort.Direction.ASC);
    reader.setSort(sorts);
    return reader;
  }

 @Bean
 public ItemProcessor<PaymentAudit, PaymentAudit> processor() {
    LOG.info("Inside Processor Method");
    return new PaymentPortalNOSQLProcessor();

 }

@Bean
public ItemWriter<PaymentAudit> writer() {
    LOG.info("Inside Writer Method");
    return new PaymentPortalNOSQLWriter();
}

@Bean
Job job(JobBuilderFactory jbf, StepBuilderFactory sbf, 
 PaymentPortalNOSQLProcessor processor,
        ItemWriter<? super PaymentAudit> writer) {

    Step s1 = sbf.get("local").<PaymentAudit, 
 PaymentAudit>chunk(100).reader(mongoReader()).processor(processor)
            .writer(writer).listener(listener).build();

    return jbf.get("etl").incrementer(new 
  RunIdIncrementer()).start(s1).build();
}

}
```

PaymentPortalNOSQLWriter:

```
 @Bean
 public FileWriter Mongowriter(){
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        String fullPath =OUTPUT_FILENAME + FILENAME_EXTN;
        writer = new FileWriter(fullPath);
        writer.write("[");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Exception occured in MongoWriter() :: 
    ApplicationConfiguration", e);
    }
    return writer;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(List items) throws Exception {


  } 


 }
```

PaymentPortalJobListener

```
 @Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;


  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
      long checkpoint = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOG.info("ExamResult Job starts at : {} " , checkpoint / (1_000 * 1.0));
  }

  @Override
   public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    if(stepExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED){
        LOG.info("ExamResult job completed successfully");
        try {
            FileWriter saveWriter = 
   (FileWriter)appContext.getBean("paymentPortalWriter");
            saveWriter.write("{}");
            saveWriter.flush();
            saveWriter.close();
        } catch (BeansException | IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Exception occured in afterStep() :: PaymentPortal", 
   e);
        }
    }
    return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
}
}
```

PaymentPortalNOSQLProcessor:

```
  public class PaymentPortalNOSQLProcessor implements 
 ItemProcessor<PaymentAudit, PaymentAudit> {
 private static final Logger LOG = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(PaymentPortalNOSQLProcessor.class);

@Override
public PaymentAudit process(PaymentAudit bean) throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("Processor method");
    return bean;

}
}
```

Gradle Build:

```
   buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
 }

 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse'
 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
 apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

 group = 'com.example'
 version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
 sourceCompatibility = 1.8

 repositories {
mavenCentral()
 }


dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')

//compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")



compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
compile group:'org.springframework.boot', name:'spring-boot-configuration- 
 processor'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testImplementation('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test')
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
//testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'

 }
```

Comment: PaymentPortalNOSQLWriter.write() method is empty.

Comment: So It's actually my Reader that does not not return any of the information that it read

Answer (score 0):

I see a small confusion here about I/O so I will try to make it clear.

One of the main features of Spring Batch is declarative I/O. This means that you don't need to write the code to deal with I/O, instead you *declare* what you want to do and Spring Batch will do the I/O for you. Your `Mongowriter` bean contains the code to actually write data, but it shouldn't. Since you need to write to a flat file, you can use the `FlatFileItemWriter`, for example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<String> flatFileItemWriter() {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<String>()
            .name("flatFileItemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("data.txt"))
            .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
            .build();
}
```

This configuration code *declares* the intention of what we need to write and where to write it, but not the actual writing (opening/closing the file, calling the writer, etc) which is handled by Spring Batch. By the way, the issue of your file not being created is due to the `open` method not being called on your writer with your code example. This should be fixed if your writer is correctly configured as shown above.

The second point is that you probably did this because you want to add `[` and `]` around the written items (From seeing `writer.write("[");` in your code). Another time, there is way to do this declaratively by using the `FlatFileHeaderCallback` and `FlatFileFooterCallback` APIs. For example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<String> flatFileItemWriter() {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<String>()
            .name("flatFileItemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("data.txt"))
            .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
            .headerCallback(writer -> writer.write('['))
            .footerCallback(writer -> writer.write(']'))
            .build();
}
```

Hope this helps.